# openCV cvRetrieveFrame or cvReleaseCapture memory leak on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm getting a memory leak in this code and I'm not able to find what I'm doing wrong.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile([[url path] UTF8String]);

while (cvGrabFrame(capture)) {    
  IplImage *frame = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);

  if (frame) {
    [...]
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

If I remove cvRetrieveFrame the memory leak disappears. If I change cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame with one cvQueryFrame the same behavior happens.

The behavior is the same with cvReleaseCapture enabled or commented out. So it's probably something related to that, but I can't figure out what.

I'm using openCV r7286 on iOS.

Comment: How did you detect the memory leak, and how much memory it leaks every iteration?

Comment: I use Instruments and do allocation snapshots. The amount of memory leaked depends on the movie resolution, it can be 10MB/one run or a lot more. With a hi-res video running it twice I can make it run out of memory and die.

Comment: I don't know how old r7286 is, so I suggest you stick with the official release packages.

Comment: https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone this is what I'm using. I need something that was added 3 months ago.

Comment: That is a port done by somebody else to iOS, therefore not an **official** release. This revision is almost 1000 commits behind the latest version. I'm voting to close this thread since is too specific to your case. I see no leak using OpenCV 2.3.1 for Mac/Windows/Linux.

Comment: There is at least one confirmed bug in their tracker: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1481. Maybe someone has a workaround. If you can't reproduce it that doesn't mean it doesn't exist, as you can see in that bug report. It's not specific to my case.

Comment: That is an entirely different bug. In that case, the memory leak is produced by opening and closing the capture interface a number of times inside the loop. That is not what you are doing here.

Comment: I found the bug in openCV, fixed it, sent a patch which was accepted. Which will be included to 2.4.0. It was not in my code. This question was entirely relevant. Please at least accept that you were wrong.

Comment: **I would if I were**, but I didn't at any moment say that it wasn't a real problem on iOS. I tested your code on each of the other systems before stating that it didn't happened with them. Also there's a high chance that the bug reference isn't related to the one you discovered. I'll admit this though: all the suggestions I gave were good and valid, and I love to see ppl contributing to OpenCV. +1 to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in openCV. A fix is available in the latest trunk.

Comment: Awesome, please share the link to the [patch submission](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1837). The fix was applied in r8146.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like this?

```
IplImage *frame;
while (cvGrabFrame(capture)) 
{  
     frame = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);    
     if (frame) {     [...]   } 
     else {     break;   } 
}
```

just declare only one pointer, not many

Answer (score 0):

cvRetrieveFrame doesn't do something very complicated. I suppose you're leaking memory in this part of your code:

```
if (frame) {
 [...]
}
```

How sure are you that part is not leaking memory? Care to share that bit?

Comment: I commented out that whole block and the memory leak is still present. In the mean time I found this bug report: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1481

Comment: Can you do a quick test, see if this 
IplImage *frame = cvCloneImage(cvRetrieveFrame(capture));
changes anything. That bug report is kind of related but isn't really the same issue, though I might be wrong.

Comment: And you're compiling OpenCv from source right? or you're using binary libraries? If you've got the code it's easy to check whether the code is deallocating the memory in the right place.

Comment: I'm just rebuilding the code from source to see if I can debug it.

Comment: cvCloneImage(cvRetrieveFrame(capture)) && cvReleaseImage of this unfortunately doesn't change anything.

Comment: The minimal test you should be doing is remove everything from the loop, except the call that retrieves the frame: `IplImage *frame = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);` If that leaks , you have a problem with that port of OpenCV to iOS.

Comment: How did it? I had a quick look at the code, I'm not an ios/objective-c coder, but going to edit the answer maybe helps you to find the answer.

Comment: Figured it out, it was a memory leak in opencv. I'm adding a patch in their ticketing system right now.

Answer (score 0):

declare IplImage* frame once above while loop. Or free the allocated Frame pointer after every iteration.